# Retrofit. Пример кода

Tags: android, retrofit

Добрый день. Хочу увидеть пример get запроса с помощью библиотеки Retrofit и как полученные данные записать в view.

Было бы прекрасно, если бы объяснили принцип работы. Спасибо.

Comment: Данные записать в View ? Вы наверное имели ввиду использовать данные? Типо сделать Get запрос и показать например картинку в MainActivity ?

Comment: Посмотрите [этo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381710/how-to-call-simple-get-method-using-retrofit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Схема работы с Retrofit 2

1/ Создаём класс, который будет инициализировать Ретрофит. Для этого пишем, например, так:

```
public class Calls {

private Retrofit retrofit;
private OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpBuilder;
private HttpLoggingInterceptor logging;
private APIService service;
private Gson gson = null;
private static Calls calls;


private Calls() {

        if (logging == null) {
            logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

            //насколько подробные логи выводить в LogCat
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY); //очень подробно
        }

        if (okHttpBuilder == null) {
            okHttpBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            okHttpBuilder.addInterceptor(logging); //добавить логгирование в качестве перехватчика вызывов
        }

        if (gson == null) {
            gson = new GsonBuilder() //создаем основной GSON объект
                    .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd") //1990-01-31
                    .excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.FINAL, Modifier.TRANSIENT, Modifier.STATIC)
                    .create();
        }


        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder() //создаем основной RETROFIT объект
                    .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL_API) //ваш сервер
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .client(okHttpBuilder.build())
                    .build();
        }

        if (service == null) { //этот сервис работает как Синглтон
            service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        }
    }
```

2/ Далее, отдельно создаём интерфейс, который будет реализовывать сами запросы:

```
public interface APIService {
    @GET("photos/{path}")
    Call<List<RestPhotos>> getUsersPhotos(
            @Header("Authorization") String header,
            @Path("path") String user_id
    );
}
```

3/ в классе, который управляет вызовами (Calls) или в другом, нужном вам, контроллере, создаём объект, который возьмёт имеющийся созданный сервис service и вызовет метод интерфейса. Полученный результат запишет куда нужно.
Например:

```
public void getUsersPhotos(@NonNull final String user_id) {

        String header = String.format("Token %s", UserModel.getUserServerToken());

        Call<List<RestPhotos>> call = service.getUsersPhotos(header, socialUid);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<RestPhotos>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<RestPhotos>> call, Response<List<RestPhotos>> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    new RestPhotos(response.body(), user_id).execute((Void) null);
                } else {
                    //response.code() можно вывести в лог ошибки
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<RestPhotos>> call, Throwable t) {
                //лог ошибки
            }
        });
    }
```

4/ Для обработки этого кода-примера, я ввёл ещё одно понятие - RestPhotos - объект, который будет управлять парсингом ответа. В нём мы указываем поля, которые есть в ответе сервера и, в отдельном потоке, получаем их, чтобы сохранить.

Код класса-парсера целиком:

```
public class RestPhotos extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    public RestPhotos(List<RestPhotos> response, String user_id) {
        this.restPhotosList = response;
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    private List<RestPhotos> restPhotosList;
    private String user_id;


    @SerializedName("photo_id")
    private String photoId;

    @SerializedName("small_uri")
    private String smallUri;

    @SerializedName("large_uri")
    private String largeUri;

    public String getPhotoId() {
        return photoId;
    }

    public String getSmallUri() {
        return smallUri;
    }

    public String getLargeUri() {
        return largeUri;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        if ((restPhotosList.size() > 0) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(user_id))) { //если массив ответа не пустой и у нас есть user_id
            for (RestPhotos restPhotoItem : restPhotosList ) { //перебираем весь массив
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(restPhotoItem.getPhotoId())) { //если у элемента есть photo_id
                    PictureModel pictureModel = PictureModel.getModelFromPhotoId(restPhotoItem.getPhotoId()); //тогда пытаемся найти в базе такой элемент
                    if (pictureModel == null) {
                        pictureModel = new PictureModel(); //если такого элемента нет в базе, то создаем новый
                    }
                    //устанавливаем все значения и сохраняем
                    pictureModel.setUserId(user_id);
                    pictureModel.setPhotoId(restPhotoItem.getPhotoId());
                    pictureModel.setSmallUri(restPhotoItem.getSmallUri());
                    pictureModel.setLargeUri(restPhotoItem.getLargeUri());

pictureModel.save();

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Надеюсь, это поможет вам разобраться с Ретрофитом! )