# Запросы в retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Как можно сделать запрос такого типа в Retrofit?

```
somesite.somedomen/helloworld?text=hello&name=Andrey
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543327/retrofit-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0

Comment: Вот ссылка на доку https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html

Answer (score 0):

Если предположить что

```
BASE_URL = "somesite.somedomen/"
```

То ваш запрос будет выглядеть примерно так

```
@GET("helloworld")
Call<ApiPOJO> getHelloworld(@Query("text") String text, @Query("name") String name);
```